# How to duplicate div in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am using innerHtml to show html content from variable in angular but it is not supporting external style and ngFor also.in the following screen whenever user click on the add service button then one row should increment. [image]
this is the data having in service list with.
[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <label class="mobileNumberLabel " for="mobilrNumber">Select Service</label>
    <div class="nice-wrap">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single nice-textbox"  style="width: 105%">
      <optgroup *ngFor="let item of serviceObject" label='{{item.categoryName}}'>
        <option *ngFor="let service of item.services">
          {{service.serviceName}} -&nbsp;&nbsp;<span >{{item.categoryName}}</span> 
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </select></div>
  </div>
```

I tried with innerHtml

```
 <div [innerHTML]="divItem"></div>
```

but it is showing like this[image]

Comment: That's probably because the `innerHTML` was not compiled by Angular. So it's not going to be rendered like that. Is there any specific reason why you're using `innerHTML` in the first place? If yes and you can't use a different approach, you might have to use a Dynamic Component for this.

Comment: @SiddAjmera there is no specific reason as i am beginner for angular . i don't have idea how to make it workable so from yesterday i am trying this but not getting how to do this

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add a reactive form dynamically into the HTML.

I came across this situation some time back as I had to add new paragraphs dynamically.

In this code, I have a text area as input for the paragraph. I can add a paragraph by clicking on the `Add New Paragraph` button and delete a paragraph by clicking on the `Remove` button.

> .html file should have -

```
<div formArrayName="contentDescriptions">
  <div *ngFor="let contentItem of contentDescriptions.controls; let i=index">
    <textarea [formControlName]="i" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="6" placeholder="Enter Description"></textarea>
    <button (click)="deleteContentDescription(i)"> Remove</button>        
  </div>

  <div>
    <button (click)="addNewParagraph()">
      <span class="icon icon-plus"></span>  Add New Paragraph
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> .ts file should have -

```
form = this.fb.group({
  contentDescriptions: this.fb.array([
    this.fb.control('')
  ])
});

get contentDescriptions() {
  return this.form.get('contentDescriptions') as FormArray;
};

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(){
  this.form.patchValue({
    contentDescriptions: this.contentSelected.descriptionArray
  });
}

addNewParagraph(){
   this.contentDescriptions.push(this.fb.control(''));
}

deleteContentDescription(i){
  this.contentDescriptions.removeAt(i);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't work the way you envision it to work, based on your question. When you write a template in Angular, it's actually not HTML -- it's a custom Angular syntax known to the Angular compiler (`ngc`). Your templates are transformed to TypeScript code which manipulates the DOM based on the model (which is then transformed to JavaScript by `tsc` so it can be executed by the browser).

This transformation is happening while you're compiling your code. When it reaches user's browsers, there's nothing of Angular templates left in it: no `*ngFor`, no `{{` interpolation.

Therefore, setting `innerHTML` to Angular's syntax (such as `*ngFor` or `{{ }}`) won't work, because you're trying to do in run-time of the application. You'll have to tweak your logic and the way you're building templates to a more structural way.

Instead of setting a string with `{{ a }}` which you `[innerHTML]` into an element, switch your logic so that you have an object, for example, `{ a: 'value' }`, and pre-define your template such as `{{ obj.a }}` in that element.